# If there is a bijection $f: X\rightarrow Y$, prove that there exists an isomorphism $\phi :S_X\rightarrow S_Y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism

> If there is a bijection $f: X\rightarrow Y$, prove that there exists an isomorphism $\phi :S_X\rightarrow S_Y$.

Here $S_X$ denotes the group of all permutations of $X$, i.e., the bijections $X\to X$ and the group operation is composition.

I know that $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality because of the bijection. I define $\phi:S_X \rightarrow S_Y$ by $\phi : a \rightarrow f\circ a\circ f^{-1}$ Then I suppose $\phi^{-1}$ can be defined as $b\rightarrow f^{-1} \circ b\circ f$.

I think this is close but I haven't showed that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. But once I do I can show isomorphism.

Comment: By $S_X$ you mean the group of permutations over $X$?all bijections from $X $onto itself?

Comment: @BigM Yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\phi(a\circ b)=  f\circ (a\circ b)\circ f^{-1}=(f\circ a\circ f^{-1})\circ (f \circ b\circ f^{-1})=\phi(a)\circ \phi(b)$

Comment: Why $f\circ (a\circ b)\circ f^{-1}=(f\circ a\circ f^{-1})\circ (f \circ b\circ f^{-1})$?

Comment: Because $f$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** What is a permutation? It is bijection from a set to
    itself.

**2.** The composition of two bijection functions is bijection.

Comment: Your definition of permutation is not correct. It needs to be bijective.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Usually $S_X$ denotes the symmetric group on a **finite set** X. The injection from a finite set to itself is bijection. :)

Comment: I disagree with the "usually".

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft +1 for disagree. Anyway, I will change it. Thanks

Comment: @user31009 In a group, the elements have inverses. So how do you invert injective but non-surjective maps on an infinite set?