# Let $X,Y$ be sets , $\phi: X\to Y$ is a bijection. Find a isomorphism $\rho : Sym(X) \to Sym(Y)$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $X,Y$ be sets , $\phi: X\to Y$ is a bijection.

Find a isomorphism $\rho : Sym(X) \to Sym(Y)$.

My attempt:

$\rho(\sigma)=\sigma^{-1}\phi\sigma$.

**$\rho$ injective:**

I show that $\rho(\sigma_1)=\rho(\sigma_2)\implies \sigma_1=\sigma_2$.

Suppose $\rho(\sigma_1)=\rho(\sigma_2)$ such that $ \sigma_1\neq\sigma_2$.

$\rho(\sigma_1)=\rho(\sigma_2)\implies \sigma_1^{-1}\phi\sigma_1=\sigma_2^{-1}\phi\sigma_2\implies \phi=\sigma_1\sigma_2^{-1}\phi\sigma_2\sigma_1^{-1} \underset{(*)}{\implies} \sigma_2\sigma_1^{-1}=\{Id\}\implies \sigma_2=\sigma_1$.

I have a problem how to show surjective and well-defined.

For showing well-defined I have to prove that $\sigma_1=\sigma_2 \implies \rho(\sigma_1)=\rho(\sigma_2)$, it looks very trivial to me and I am not sure how to prove it.

Any help is welcome thanks !

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157162/if-there-is-a-bijection-f-x-rightarrow-y-prove-that-there-exists-an-isomorph). You also have to show that $\rho$ is a group homomorphism. Conjugation is bijective, so this is also known. Careful, we define  $\rho(\phi)=\sigma^{-1}\phi\sigma$, not what you did.

Comment: The correct way to define $\rho(\sigma)$ is $\phi\sigma\phi^{-1}$.